# How can I change this JS calendar pop up's output to be PHP's date('W') output

Tags: php, javascript, html

What I am trying/wanting to do is changing the output of this JS calendar to become the same output format as PHP's date('W').

So for example, I am using the JS calendar pop up found here: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/

When you choose a date from the calendar, an output is automatically generated and filled into the textbox in the format day/month/year

However, I dont want the output in the datebox to be generated as day month year....instead I want the generated output to be the week number user has chosen in the calendar...

So say I choose 8th January 2011 in the calendar pop up. Currently it will fill into the textbox 08/01/11...BUT what SHOULD happen is it puts into that textbox 2 as January 8th is the 2nd week in that year...How can I do this? I am stuck because if a user's current date is end of december and End date is january of the next year PHP's date command will think we are at a new year and it will mess up...I hope I am being clear...

This is what is happening...

User interface they have 2 textboxes,

each text box is associated to a calendar pop up. The output somehow wont be day/month/ear but instead the week of the year...

Once user chooses their options php in the backend will see what time gap the user has chosen using the function PHP's date ('W')

I am stuck on how to change the calendar date format into php's date('W') format.

Comment: JS's date object doesn't have a "week of year" option. You could probably fake it with a "day of Year / 52", but that'd off depending on what day the year started on, and leapyears.

Comment: yeah thats exactly why im super stuck on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want you are going to have to write your own function, theres no magic built in way to do it in JavaScript like there is in php

http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/33796/14863/Calculate-ISO-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html

http://www.irt.org/script/914.htm

http://javascript.about.com/library/blweekyear.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/gregorianwknum.aspx

http://www.onlineconversion.com/day_week_number.htm - working example, you can see how they do it by viewing their source

Comment: that works but how will it carry on the year? so if one of the textbox is this year and the next textbook the user chooses the next year how will i find the week difference in between? write my own function?

Comment: I would write my own function, in order to work out the difference we will need three inputs. The first years week, the second years week and how many weeks in a year (this is a constant value as it will never change). The first thing we need to do is work how many weeks we have left in the current year, so in order to do that we take the number of weeks in a year (52) and minus year 1 week count from that, so if we had 32 for the first year we would have 52 -32 thus giving us 20. We then take this value and plus the second years week value to that, so if we had say 12 for the second years

Comment: week we would have 20 +12 thus giving us 32. So there for if we had year 1 with a week value of 32 and year 2 with a week value of 12 the difference is 32

With that said all we need to do in order to work out the difference is
    (max_weeks_per_year -year_one_week) +year_two_week

Answer (score 1):

[Jacob Wrights Date.format](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/) supports 'W', which gives this:

> ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP
>   4.1.0)

Comment: I don't have a high level of confidence in the way that function calculates it. The PHP source code runs about 50 lines of conditions that take into account leap years , first day of the week of the year, etc.